# Tabbarview and Pageview without being able to swipe between pages

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it possible to create a `TabBarView` or `PageView` without letting the user swipe between pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` as your `physics` argument.

Comment: That works for the PageView, thanks! Any way to create the same effect with a TabBarView?

Comment: A `TabBarView` is mostly just a wrapper around a `PageView`. I would just use a `PageView` (with `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`), and add a listener to your `TabController` that calls `jumpTo` on the `PageView`'s `PageController`.